# Why does Python require double the RAM to read a file?

Tags: python

I am reading a file which is `24 GB` in size. I am using

```
lines = open(fname).read().splitlines()
```

and it seems that when reading the lines, it always uses ~double the amount of RAM which should be needed. It uses about `50 GB` for my current script (after it jumps up to 50 it goes back down to 28) but every time I use this kind of line to read a file in `Python` it generally uses double the file size before dropping down to a size that I would expect.

Any idea why this is happening or how I can avoid it?

Comment: Is there any reason you need to keep the entire file in memory?

Comment: Because Python is loading the result of `open(fname).read()` in memory and then runs `splitlines()` on that.

Comment: Your code explicitly creates one huge string in memory (result of `open(fname).read()`) which is afterwards split to individual lines by `.splitlines()`. Huge string cannot be garbage-collected before splitting operation occurs. Any reason you need whole file in memory at once? Python has mechanisms for lazy file reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RAM Usage: Filesize * 1: Read the entire file into memory

```
open(fname).read()
```

RAM Usage Filesize * 2: Allocate enough space in a list to split the newlines

```
open(fname).read().splitlines()
```

After this operation is complete, the RAM usage drops back down to about Filesize * 1 because the full text of the file isn't needed anymore and it can be garbage-collected.

---

If you don't need the full text of the file at once, and are only operating on lines, then just iterate over the file

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file contains 25Gb of data, then `file_handle.read()` will return a string that is 25Gb in size.  When you split that string, you create a list  that holds strings that add up to 25Gb of data (plus additional string overhead for each one).  So you end up using about twice the memory.

The big string will get reaped almost immediately by the garbage collector making the memory available for new python objects to occupy, but that doesn't mean that the memory is completely freed to the operating system (due to optimizations in python's memory allocator).

A better approach is to accumulate a list of lines one at a time:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = list(f)
```

You'll only hold approximately one line in memory from the file at a time<sup>1</sup> so then your memory use will be mostly just the memory to store the list.

<sup><sup>1</sup>This isn't exactly true ... pythons internal line buffering will probably have a couple kb of data at any given time buffered...</sup>

Of course, there might also be the option to process the file iteratively:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        process(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `read` returns a string of the entire file, which is not garbage collected until a list is returned from `splitlines`. If you *need* the file in the memory, try `readlines` method:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

`read()` tries to load the whole file in memory. With overhead and buffers, this can exceed the size of the file. Then you split the contents of the file into lines, because python allocates new memory for each line.

Can your code be refactored to use `readline()` and process the lines one by one instead? this would reduce the amount of memory that your program uses at once.

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        # process a single line, maybe keeping some state elsewhere.
```

However, if you still need to load all of the lines in memory at once, use `readlines()` instead:

```
with open(filename) as f:
     lines = f.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

`read()` is returning a single `str` with the whole file data in it. `splitlines` is returning the `list` of `lines` with the same data. The whole file data isn't cleaned up until after `splitlines` creates the `list`, so you store two copies of the data for a brief period.

If you want to minimize this overhead (and still strip newlines), you can try:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip('\r\n') for line in f]
```

If you can process line by line (don't need whole `list` at once), it's even better:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
```

which avoids storing more than two lines at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You read the whole file into memory with:

```
open(fname).read()
```

In a second step you create of list from this string with `.splitlines()`.
During this time the string stays in memory but you copy the parts of the
string into the list, line-by-line. Only after your are finished creating the 
list, the string can be garbage collected. So during this time you store
all information twice and hence need twice the memory.

You could use `open(fname).readlines()` or read the file line-by-line to reduce
the memory footprint.